# How to host an HTML file with ngrok?

Tags: html, text-files, host, ngrok

Is it possible to host, instead of a web app, a HTML file with NGROK? I really don't know anything about NGROK, I just used it to host a server for a Twilio app, and am wanting to use it to host a HTML file for another one of my projects. Also, anybody know how to create a HTML file on a Mac? Thanks in advance. Or, If I can't use NGROK, anybody know something as easy and free is it is that I could use for hosting a HTML file on my computer. I need to be able to change the file in real time, so google sites and stuff like that are out of the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No. [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) only tunnels traffic, so it can't actually *serve* the HTML file for you.

You can, however, serve a directory of files very easily. One of the quickest ways to start a server is with python. From the command line, `cd` to the directory containing your HTML files and run:

```
$ python3 -m http.server
```

Or for python 2:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then, in another terminal, run `ngrok`.

Comment: In your first example, is "SimpleHTTPServer" the name of the directory or part of the command?

Comment: It is part of the command. It runs the python [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html).

Comment: Can I do the same with, instead of a directory, a single file?

Comment: Sure, just put only the single file in the directory and name it `index.html`.

Comment: Could I do the same with, instead of a HTML file, an audio or other media file?

Comment: Absolutely. Don't be afraid to just try stuff out!

Comment: I mean, could I have the webpage open to an audio file instead of a "Directory Listing for /" page with the audio as a subpage?

Comment: It sounds like you should ask a new question about this specifically.

Answer (score 36):

Yes. ngrok now has a built-in fileserver. https://ngrok.com/docs/http/#serve-directory-files

### Without password

Example command for Linux/mac:

```
ngrok http file:///Users/alan/share
```

Windows:

```
ngrok http "file:///C:\Users\alan\share"
```

This will create an HTTP server, sharing all files in the directory `/Users/alan/share`.

### With password

Example command for Linux/mac:

```
ngrok http -auth="user:password" file:///Users/alan/share
```

Windows:

```
ngrok http -auth="user:password" "file:///C:\Users\alan\share"
```

This will create an HTTP server with a basic auth username and password, sharing all files in the directory `/Users/alan/share`.

Comment: what is the correct way to point the directory in Windows? I tried file://C:/app/asd but nothing happend

Comment: @RoyHabeahan Great question. I've updated my answer in response.

Comment: updated docs link: https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels#http-tunnels-file-urls

Comment: Updated docs link: https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/tunnels/http-tunnels#file-url

Answer (score 1):

thanks to [Zach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2171182/zach) that explained above the file directory of ngrok

When you want to server HTML files on ngrok
after you run command

```sh
ngrok http <port_number>
```

You go to <your_ngrok_address>:

```
http://your_ngrok_adress.ngrok.io
```

You go to the page that in the top section of it, if you haven't configured your **ngrok auth_token** there is this message to **sign-up into free account to server HTML files**, click the link for sign-up.

After you signed up, you'll be redirected to your dashboard which explained below command to run:

```sh
ngrok authtoken <your_auth_token>
```

After you run the above command then run the first command again:

```sh
ngrok http "file:///<your_html file location/direcoty>"
```

there you'll se your files directory, navigate through them to reach your HTML file/directory (if neccessary) there it'll serve them for you.

Answer (score 0):

To forward to a local file:/// URL,
first create an account at ngrok: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/signup

Your auth token will be available on your dashboard at  https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken

Add the ngrok auth token to your machine using:

```
ngrok config add-authtoken <YOUR_NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN>
```

Then start the ngrok server:

```
ngrok http <FILE_PATH_OF_FOLDER>
```

e.g.,

```
ngrok http file:///Users/some_user/Desktop/
```

Your local file will get forwarded to the forwarding URL through `ngrok`.
Go to your forwarding URL to look at the files.